SwiftUI - Image Cropped using UIBezierPath not cut at the good location
Hey Im build a cropping document app.
Im getting the image converted from CIImage to UIImage from the camera.
Once its arrives in my SwiftUI View, I draw a cropping view above.
Then I crop the view using UIBezierPath.
Something in the cropping is somehow wrong because the shape is correct but the content of the picture is not.
Here is the struct holding my points:
   struct PathPoint {
    var topLeft: CGPoint
    var topRight: CGPoint
    var bottomLeft: CGPoint
    var bottomRight: CGPoint
    
    init(topLeft: CGPoint = .zero, topRight: CGPoint = .zero, bottomLeft: CGPoint = .zero, bottomRight: CGPoint = .zero) {
        self.topLeft = topLeft
        self.topRight = topRight
        self.bottomLeft = bottomLeft
        self.bottomRight = bottomRight
    }
   
    func createBezierPath() -> UIBezierPath {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: topLeft)
        path.addLine(to: topRight)
        path.addLine(to: bottomRight)
        path.addLine(to: bottomLeft)
        path.close() // Close the path to form a rectangle
        return path
    }
    
    func createCGPath() -> CGPath {
        createBezierPath().cgPath
    }

}


Here is place where the cropping code :

    func imageByApplyingClippingBezierPath(_ path: UIBezierPath) -> UIImage? {
        guard let maskedImage = imageByApplyingMaskingBezierPath(path),
              let cgImage = maskedImage.cgImage else { return nil }
        
        guard let cropped = cgImage.cropping(to: path.bounds) else {
            print(#function, "could not crop for bounds \(path.bounds)")
            return nil
        }
        let croppedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cropped)
        
        return croppedImage
    }
    
    func imageByApplyingMaskingBezierPath(_ path: UIBezierPath) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        context.saveGState()

        path.addClip()
        draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))

        guard let maskedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else { return nil }

        context.restoreGState()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return maskedImage
    }




You're not taking scaling into account. I assume you are letting the user take a photo... you display the captured UIImage in a UIImageView... then allow the user to tap/drag the corners? If so, what is the Content Mode of your image view (scaleToFill / .scaleAspectFit / .scaleAspectFill)? If that's not what you're doing, explain your process prior to trying to clip-out the path.

The user is taking a picture,
and the image is displayed into an Image (swift ui) - which is there cropped.
The Image struct is being applied a resizable() modifier.
You mean the cropping is applied to the screen size and the image ? How should I scale

@DonMag.
Thank your rescale insight.
I have rescaled my image to fit my screen size, then applied the crop. Then detect my documents with my model to apply the crop on its corner.
Now the cut is done where it should.

Glad that helped. You may want to Answer your own question - with example code showing how it's working now - for the benefit of other users who may come across this issue.

As @DonMag noticed I was missing the scaling part, where the UIImage size gets a fitting size to the screen on which we apply the cropping bounds/draw.
In order to to I convert my CIImage like such:
    func convertCIImageToUIImage(ciImage: CIImage) -> UIImage? {
        let context = MetalDevice.shared.context
        if let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) {
            return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage).scale(newSize: self.view.bounds.size)
        }
                
        return nil
    }


where the UIImage.scale(newSize:) extension is:

    func scale(newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {

        let scaleFactorWidth = newSize.width / self.size.width
        let scaleFactorHeight = newSize.height / self.size.height
        
        let scale = min(scaleFactorWidth, scaleFactorHeight)

        
        let newHeight = self.size.height * scale
        let newWidth = self.size.width * scale
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(.init(width: newWidth, height: newHeight), true, 0.0)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
        
        let newImage: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage ?? self
    }

Notice it the scaling could have been directly to the CIImage using the CILanczosScaleTransform filter.
and it would have been applied in an extension as such:
    func lanczosScale(to bounds: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        let targetWidth = bounds.width
        let targetHeight = bounds.height

        let originalWidth = extent.width
        let originalHeight = extent.height
        let scaleX = targetWidth / originalWidth
        let scaleY = targetHeight / originalHeight

        let scale = min(scaleX, scaleY)

        let scaleFilter = CIFilter(name: "CILanczosScaleTransform")!
        scaleFilter.setValue(self, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        scaleFilter.setValue(scale, forKey: kCIInputScaleKey)
        scaleFilter.setValue(1.0, forKey: kCIInputAspectRatioKey) 

        if let outputImage = scaleFilter.outputImage {
            let context = MetalDevice.shared.context
            if let cgImage = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent) {
                let resizedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
                
                return resizedImage
            }
            return nil
        }
        return nil
    }

The question is now, in order to keep the resolution, should I apply some resizing to the buffer directly ? But it's a further research.

Hmmm... you really should not have to do any image resizing. One of your comments stated "detect my documents with my model" ... are you getting the 4 points for the "document outline" from a shape detection, as opposed to user-tapping? If so, if you can put together a [mre] I can give you a different - possibly better - approach.

Other solution, at the end I went for OpenCV.
After some research I found the corresponding algorithms
fillPoly - In order to crop the drawn areas.
getPerspectiveTransform to warpPerspective - To align the cropped area to the screen size.
I had to implement them in Objc++, in order to create a bridge between my swift app and the opencv.
In order to get rid of my model - Im currently looking at the hough line transform method. Which will detect the corners of my docs.
If someone wants to try heres the wrapped .mm code.
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
#import "OpenCVHelper.h"
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#import <opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

@implementation OpenCVHelper

+(UIImage *)cropImage: (UIImage *) image toPoints:(NSArray<NSValue *> *)points  {
    cv::Mat cvImage ;
    UIImageToMat(image,cvImage);
    
    std::vector<cv::Point> p2fs;
    for (NSValue *value in points) {
        CGPoint cgPoint = [value CGPointValue];
        p2fs.push_back(cv::Point((int)cgPoint.x, (int)cgPoint.y));
    }
    
    cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(cvImage.size(), CV_8UC1);
    
    cv::fillPoly(mask, p2fs, cv::Scalar(255));
    
    cv::Mat croppedImage;
    cvImage.copyTo(croppedImage, mask);
    return MatToUIImage(croppedImage);
}

+(UIImage *)performPerspectiveTransformWithPoints:(NSArray<NSValue *> *)points toSize:(CGSize)size toImage:(UIImage *) image {
    cv::Mat mat ;
    UIImageToMat(image,mat);
    // Detection: Create MatOfPoint2f for source points
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> p2fs;
    // Convert NSArray<NSValue *> to std::vector<cv::Point2f>
    for (NSValue *value in points) {
        CGPoint cgPoint = [value CGPointValue];
        p2fs.push_back(cv::Point2f(cgPoint.x, cgPoint.y));
    }
    // Destination: Create MatOfPoint2f for destination points
    float screenWidth = size.width;
    float screenHeight = size.height;
    
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> destinationPoints = {
        cv::Point2f(0, 0),
        cv::Point2f(screenWidth, 0),
        cv::Point2f(screenWidth, screenHeight),
        cv::Point2f(0, screenHeight)
    };
    
    // Get perspective transformation matrix
    cv::Mat transformMatrix = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(p2fs, destinationPoints);
    
    // Perform warpPerspective to apply the transformation
    cv::Mat warped;
    cv::warpPerspective(mat, warped, transformMatrix, cv::Size((int)screenWidth, (int)screenHeight));
    
    return MatToUIImage(warped);
}
@end

